# how to validate regular expression in pretty-config.xml

Tags: regex

Following is url maping in pritty-config.xml here i want to add regular expression in url and validate my url with proper regex.
Following value i need to validate=
params={userIds:[147,location_id:1}

but i getting error at time of run this code 
error is

Fatal Error at line 76 column 55: Element type "pattern" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 76; columnNumber: 55; Element type "pattern" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
<url-mapping id="bookManagement"> 
  <pattern value="/bookManagement/{[params={"userIds":[\d\],"location_id":[\d\]}]+}" /> 
  <view-id>/template/bookManagement/bookManagement.jsf</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

Comment: You have double quotes in the attribute value. Those are not allowed there (see XML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#syntax). Have you tried replacing them by `&quot;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quote instead of double quotes for the `value`attribute.

```
<pattern value='/bookManagement/{[params={"userIds":[\d\],"location_id":[\d\]}]+}' />
```